# Node is not resolving a client side module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a Node application where I want to use socket.io to communicate data to a client where it is displayed by smoothie.   I have both packages installed (via NPM) on two different node environments and in both cases in the node_modules sub-directory of my project.  One of the environments is the BeagleBone Black and the other is the Cloud9 IDE environment.   In both cases the socket.io module resolves and works fine but no combination of path names gets the smoothie module to resolve (which I can get to work if I just pull it from GitHub directly).

Here are the relevant bits of the server side code for the Cloud9 IDE:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/NotWorking.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
.
.
.
```

Here are the relevant bits from the client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="smoothie/smoothie.js"></script>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var line1 = new TimeSeries();
    var line2 = new TimeSeries();
    var socket = io.connect('http://demo-project.wisar.c9.io/');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        for (var property in data) {
            dataPoint = data[property];
        }
        line1.append(new Date().getTime(), dataPoint);
        line2.append(new Date().getTime(), 40);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: dataPoint });
    });
</script>
.
.
.
```

As I said, both modules are located in the node_modules sub directory of the project directory where the above scripts live.   The node documentation describes how includes are supposed to be resolved (http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) and I think that I can follow the path to how it resolves the link to socket.io by way of the index.js route...but it also works when I put a "/" in front which I can not find a path for.  No permutation or combination of paths makes the smoothie module resolve.   smoothie, btw, is a small charting application that can be found in npm under that name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your current file is in the same directory as `node_modules`, then to load `smoothie` try this path in src of script tag:

```
./node_modules/smoothie/smoothie.js
```

The path `smoothie/smoothie.js` is not giving the location of `smoothie.js`, which lies in `node_modules/smoothie/smoothie.js`. This worked for me, I hope this works for you.